# If 9 people play against each other twice for one point each, what is the minimum number of points you would need to be guaranteed in the top 6?

Tags: statistics

If 9 people were going to play a game against each other, two times each (each game would be 1 point), how many points would an individual person need to get to be guaranteed to be in the top 6?

I am trying to figure out the magic number for a tournament at work and we haven't been able to come to a conclusion so I'm turning to you.

Comment: 11 points will do.

Comment: How do you figure that?

Comment: There are 72 games to play.  Then you find the minimum $x$ such that $72 - 6x < x$.  If a player has $x$ points and is guaranteed to be in the top six, then in the worst case all the top six would have $x$ points and the points to be shared among the others must be such that a seventh player cannot break into the top six by collecting all of them.

Comment: Does that account for the fact that people will have to play each other and the next 6 won't be able to all win all of their games? That's the part that has been throwing me off.

Comment: It does.  It is possible to have a seven-way tie at $10$ points, but not at $11$.  Suppose each player plays eight home games and eight away games.  Seven players win all their home games and also the away games against the remaining two players.  That gives the seven-way tie, which I interpret as no guarantee to be in the top six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A score of $10\;$or more guarantees placement in the top $6$ (allowing ties for $6$-th place).

To see this, suppose player $A$ has a score of at least $10.\;$If player $A$ was not in the top $6$, there would have to be $6$ other players, each having a score of $11$ or more.$\;$But then the total of the scores would be at least $(6{\,\times\,}11) + 10 = 76$, which is impossible, since the number of games played is $72$.

However, if player $A$ has a score of $9$, it's possible for $6$ other players to have scores of $10$, in which case, $A$ will not place in the top $6$.

To see this, label the players as $1,2,3,4,5,6,A,B,C$.

We will show a tournament for which the scores are:

- $10\;$for players $1,..,6$.$\\[5pt]$

  $9\;$for player $A$.$\\[5pt]$

  $3\;$for player $B$.$\\[5pt]$

  $0\;$for player $C$.$\\[5pt]$

The above scores can be realized as follows . . .

- Player $C$ loses all games played, so player $C$ gets a score of$\;0$, and each of the other players gets $2$ points from player $C$.$\\[8pt]$

  Let players $1,...,6$ tie against each other, tie with player $A$, and beat players $B$ and $C$ on both tries, so they each get scores of $5 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 10$.$\\[8pt]$

  Let player $A$ tie against all other players except player $C$.$\;$Then the score for player $A$ is $7 + 2 = 9$.$\\[8pt]$

  It follows that player $B\;$has a score of $0 + 1 + 2 = 3$.$\\[8pt]$